# Aggregating/optimizing object.save()?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm working on import feature which allows user to create django database models from selected csv file.

Models are related which each other with foreign keys and many-to-many fields. 
There is a lot

```
object.save()
```

and `Object.objects.get(...)` in my code which, I suppose, cause it to run so slow.

When an error (for example integrity error) occurs, I need all the changes in database to be rolled back. So I'm using

```
transaction.atomic
```

decorator on my view and it works fine.

The problem is, my import is really slow. Parsing file containing ~2000 lines (which could possibly add about 1000 objects to my database) takes about 3 minutes, which is too long.

Is there a way to make it faster? I've read about

```
bulk_create
```

function, but "It does not work with many-to-many relationships.".

If this is important, I'm using postgresql.

**EDIT:**
File structure looks like this:

```
subject_name
day [A/B] begins_at - ends_at;lecturer_info
```

Then multiple lines like:

```
student_uid;student_info
```

Ok, here's the code.

```
def csv_import(market, csv_file):
    lines = [line.strip().decode('utf-8') for line in csv_file.readlines()]
    lines = [line for line in lines if line]
    pattern = re.compile(r'[0-9]+;.+')   

    week_days = {
        'monday': 0,
        .  
        .
        .
    }

    term, subject, lecturer, student = None, None, None, None

    for number, line in enumerate(lines):
        if not ';' in line:
            subject = Subject(subject_id=number, name=line, market=market)
            subject.save()
        elif not pattern.match(line):
            term_info, lecturer_info = line.split(';')  # term_info - 'day begins_at - ends_at', lecturer_info - lecturer
            term_info = term_info.replace(' - ', ' ').split()
            term = Term(term_id=number, subject=subject, day=week_days[term_info[0]], begin_at=term_info[-2],
                        ends_at=term_info[-1])

            if len(term_info) == 4:
                term.week = term_info[1]

            lecturer_info = lecturer_info.rsplit(' ', 1)
            try:
                lecturer = Lecturer.objects.get(first_name=lecturer_info[0], last_name=lecturer_info[1])
            except Lecturer.DoesNotExist:
                lecturer = Lecturer(first_name=lecturer_info[0], last_name=lecturer_info[1])
                lecturer.save()

            term.lecturer = lecturer

            term.save()
        else:
            gradebook_id, student_info = line.split(';')
            student_info = student_info.rsplit(' ', 1)
            try:
                student = TMUser.objects.get(uid=int(gradebook_id))
            except TMUser.DoesNotExist:
                student = TMUser(uid=int(gradebook_id), username='student'+gradebook_id, first_name=student_info[0],
                                 last_name=student_info[1], password=make_password('passwd'), user_group='user')
                student.save()
            student.terms.add(term)
            student.save()
```

Comment: Which bit is slow? Parsing the file or loading to DB? Can you show how you're loading it up?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I didn't mention this. I think saving/selecting from db. A haven't run profiler, but I removed all django's references from my code, used simple classes instead of django.models and tried to parse same file - it took few miliseconds then... If you want, I can edit my post and paste code.

Comment: Code will help since there is no valid answer without knowing the use case

Comment: I've pasted the code, hope this will help you.

Comment: Basically, your code does a lot of lookups without caching the results. Each time you query or create a Term or Lecturer, save the result in a dict. Then when you link them or create other stuff, you can get the object from the dict without the extra query.

Comment: You mean lecturers and users? Because terms are always created and saved in db, so what's the purpose of keeping them in dict?

Comment: See my answer below. you can reduce Lecturer queries by caching their results if they repeat a lot in the CSV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is some pseudo code to show you the basic idea of what I meant by caching results:

```
cache = {}

for number, line in enumerate(lines):
   ...
   elif not pattern.match(line):
      ...
      term = Term(term_id=number, subject=subject, ...)

      lecturer_id = (lecturer_info[0], lecturer_info[1])   #first name and last
      if cache[lecturer_id]:
         #retrieve from cache
         lecturer = cache[lecturer_id]
      else:
         try:
            lecturer = Lecturer.objects.get(first_name= lecturer_id[0], last_name= lecturer_id[1])
         except Lecturer.DoesNotExist:
            lecturer = Lecturer(first_name= lecturer_id[0], last_name= lecturer_id[1])
            lecturer.save()
         #add to cache
         cache[lecturer_id] = lecturer

      term.lecturer = lecturer
      term.save()   

      #etc.
```

Comment: I understood you for the first time ;) I'd also do this with users, because they repeat a lot. But the question is - is there any option beside that? I meant, some django feature which optimize such tasks?

Comment: I doubt it. You're optimising database operations here. A bulk operation might still help you but then you'll need to group your inserts by grouping your CSV results (you can do this quite nicely using Pandas). This could help if you could then utilise joined queries but probably not much in your case. Cache your results and you'll have optimised by at least one round trip per insert.

Comment: It's still pretty slow, but it helped a little, thanks.

Comment: In that case, try parsing the CSV into to some kind of structure (dict, dataframe etc.) and do your queries/inserts over groups. Failing that you'll have to look at your database indexes to see if they are optimised.